# RethinkDB simple filter not working?

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm learning ReQL in the web UI "Data Explorer" and have created the following "cars" table with 2 documents, in the provided "test" database:

```
[{
   "brand":  "Nissan" ,
   "id": 1 ,
   "model":  "Murano" ,
   "year": 2009
 } ,
 {
   "brand":  "Nissan" ,
   "id": 2 ,
   "model":  "Qashqai" ,
   "year": 2014
 }
]
```

While the following query returns both documents correctly:

```
r.table("cars")
```

...the following should return only the second document but why does it instead return an empty array?:

```
r.table("cars").filter(
   r.row["year"] > 2010
)
```

I got this filter query straight out of the official samples at http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples in the *SQL to ReQL cheat sheet* are in Python.

However the Data Explorer uses JavaScript. In JavaScript, `.gt` must be used instead of `>` and `()` instead of `[]`:

```
r.table("cars").filter(r.row("year").gt(2010))
```